# Aurelia Custom Elements data binding

Tags: javascript, custom-element, aurelia

I am using a custom-element with my Aurelia app. When I am binding data from my view-model with the custom-element, it is working fine. Even if I make some changes in the data in the custom-element control, the change is also reflected to the data in my view model, thanks to the two-way data binding.

However, if I make some changes in the data from the view model (using javascript), the data is not updated in the custom-element. I have replicated this problem for a simpler setting.

***Simple View Model***

```
export class Playground {

  public testObj: any;
  counter = 0;


  constructor() {
    this.testObj = {
        prop1: "This is prop1 value"           
        , collection2: [{ id: "item21" }]
    }        
  }

  updateProp1() {
    alert("before update: "+this.testObj.prop1);
    this.testObj.prop1 = "Sayan " + this.counter++;
    alert(this.testObj.prop1);
  }

  verifyChange() {
    alert(this.testObj.prop1);
  }
}
```

***Simple View***

```
<template>
<h1>
    Playground
</h1>

<div >         
    <div repeat.for="item of testObj.collection2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="prop1"
                       value.bind="$parent.testObj['prop1']">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button click.delegate="updateProp1()" class="btn btn-primary"> Update Prop1 </button>
    <button click.delegate="verifyChange()" class="btn btn-primary"> Verify Change </button>

</div>

</template>
```

Now whenever I click `Verify Change` after changing the value in textbox, the changed value comes in the alert. But, if I click the `Update Prop1` button, the `prop1` value gets updated, but the change doesn't reflect in the view. 
I am not sure exactly what I am missing.

**Note:** Instead of using `$parent.testObj['prop1']`, if `$parent.testObj.prop1` is used, the databinding works as it should. However, my actual custom-element is of generic kind and the property name is not known before hand, hence it seems that I need to keep using `$parent.testObj['prop1']` notation instead of dot notation: `$parent.testObj.prop1`.

At pointer/suggestion/feedback is appreciated.

**Update:** If anyone can point out the the difference between the dot notation and indexer notation **w.r.t. aurelia data-binding** (I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) already), that will be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an issue in earlier builds of the `aurelia/binding` module.  Here's the related issue(s):

- https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/75
- https://github.com/aurelia/binding/pull/76

I tried your view/view-model in the latest version of aurelia and everything worked. Here's a screencast of what I saw:  http://screencast.com/t/KqcuqXWjkU2

Make sure you have the latest version of the aurelia components installed- update steps here: http://blog.durandal.io/2015/05/01/aurelia-may-status-and-releases/

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I wanted to be sure.